# C# LINQ filtering

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

I have this piece of code

```
            var tblGrouped = dtCSV.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new
                {
                    product_id   = r.Field<String>("product_id"),
                    owner_org_id = r.Field<String>("owner_org_id"),
                });
```

But I want to add an additional column to filter by.  Basically if course_type_id = 1 for example.  dtCSV is the source where the course_type_id is populated.  I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
            var tblGrouped = dtCSV.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new
                {
                    product_id   = r.Field<String>("product_id"),
                    owner_org_id = r.Field<String>("owner_org_id"),
                    course_type_id = "1",
                });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to group rows which have a `course_type_id` of 1?

```
var tblGrouped = dtCSV.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<String>("course_type_id") == "1")
    .GroupBy(r => new
        {
            product_id   = r.Field<String>("product_id"),
            owner_org_id = r.Field<String>("owner_org_id"),
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add the condition first. You can do that using `.Where`:

```
var tblGrouped = dtCSV.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<String>("course_type_id") == "1")
    .GroupBy(r => new
    {
        product_id   = r.Field<String>("product_id"),
        owner_org_id = r.Field<String>("owner_org_id"),
        course_type_id = "1"
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter by use `Where` syntax
Ex. `.Where(a=>a.Field<String>("course_type_id") == "1")`